# WSO2 API for Deleting User from Group

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have successfully added a User to a Group using the WSO2 SCIM apis. Now I have to remove the User from the Group and I was not able to find any apis that support this. Can it be done and if so what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to GET the group and update (PUT) it with that specific user removed.

When you GET role, it should have all members. Then remove the user you want to remove, and send a PUT request to that group.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the Delete User section of [SCIM APIs documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/SCIM+APIs).
Similarly, you can manage groups by performing CRUD operations on the Group resource endpoint.

Comment: I think he's asking about removing a user from a group.

Comment: thanks for replying. I wanted to know how to remove a specific user from a group.